# AWS ECS restrict to only one container instance

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs

I want to only ever run one instance of my container to run at a given time. For instance say my ECS container is writing data to an EFS. The application I am running is built in such a way that multiple instances can not be writing to this data at a given time. So is there a way to make sure that ECS never starts more than one instance. I was worried that when one container was being torn down or stood up that two containers may end up running simultaneously.

I was also thinking about falling back to EC2 so that I could meet this requirement but did want to try this out in ECS.

I have tried setting the desired instances to 1 but I am worried that this will not work.

Comment: Desired count is the way to control the number of running instances in ECS. Unless you have auto scaling configured (which will change it between the configured min and max numbers), it will remain at that.

Comment: @chamal I guess my question really is. When a task becomes unhealthy say because it is under a lot of load. Will ECS Fargate wait for the first container to spin down before spinning up a new one or could a scenario exist where two containers are running at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Just set min, desired and maximum number of tasks to 1.

> [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-configure-auto-scaling.html#:~:text=To%20configure%20basic%20Service%20Auto%20Scaling%20parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-configure-auto-scaling.html#:%7E:text=To%20configure%20basic%20Service%20Auto%20Scaling%20parameters)